# maximum forest (graph theory)

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I don´t know how to prove that my following algorithm works:

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and $W =(V,T)$ a forest such that for every other forest $\hat W=(V,\hat T)$ and $l: E\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the cost function for the edges

$$\sum_{e \in T}l(e) \ge \sum_{\hat e \in \hat T}l(\hat e)$$

We call $W$ the maximum forest of the graph $G$

Algorithm: 1:  define $\hat l(e)=-l(e)$
2. Compute the minimum spanning tree with respect to $\hat l(e)$ (using Kruskal)
3.Let $F$ be the resulting set of edges of the "maximum" spanning tree
4. Let $S=\{e \in F: l(e)\gt0\}$

5. The graph $(V,S)$ is the maximum forest

$(V,S)$ is obviously a forest since $S$ is a subset of a tree.
Intuitively, $(V,S)$ is a maximum forest but I am stuck here.

I think that if my algorithm was correct for any connected Graph $G$ it would also work for any not connected Graph.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: @NoName : $l$ is in fact the cost function of the edges. Forgot to mention it. I edited it now

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Suppose by way of contradiction that $(V,S)$ is not a maximum forest, and $(V,S')$ is. Then $S'$ has an edge that $S$ doesn't have. Why did Kruskal's algorithm miss this edge?

Comment: Another suggestion: you can ignore edges with negative/non-positive weights from the start. Consider $\hat E\subseteq E$ the collection of edges with positive weights and $\hat G=(V,\hat E)$. A maximum spanning forest of $\hat G$ is probably a maximum forest of $G$.